# Forward/Backward Slash Issue in python

Tags: python

I am having a problem setting a new string to os.chdir (to change directory).

```
fullDir= '//user/Tester/diagnostics/data/'
fullDirString= fullDir+ uniqueName + '/' + folderNameRun
os.chdir(fullDirString)
```

Error code I get is `"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] System cannot find the path specified`

I have tried this to fix that issue

```
fullDir= '\\user\Tester\diagnostics\data\'
fullDirString= fullDir+ uniqueName + '\' + folderNameRun
os.chdir(fullDirString)
```

And I have tried this

```
newfullDirString= fullDirString.replace('\\', r'\')
```

However I am out of luck. Any advice?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't run. `' \'` isn't valid. You should probably read a bit more about python string escape sequences.

Comment: When using backslashes... you may want to use raw strings `r"some\string"` to prevent escaping (e.g `"\\user"` in your example is actually `\user`). But first and foremost, check your path... Windows should nowadays deal with forward slashes just fine, so I would much more suspect a typo or for some other reason the path genuinely not being found.

Comment: Try a single forward slash at the front `'/user/Tester/diagnostics/data/'`

Comment: I did try using raw string. Still had the same issue. I will try the single forward slash

Answer (score 1):

What about using `os.path` module? It should take care about the path construction depending on the current OS

```
from os import path
fullDir = '//user/Tester/diagnostics/data/'
fullDirString= path.join(path.normpath(fullDir),uniqueName,folderNameRun)
os.chdir(fullDirString)
```

### Edit 1:

Integrated the `path.normpath` to normalize the initial path, as suggested by @zmike

Comment: Suggestion: `fullDir = os.path.normpath(fullDir)`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, just for laziness I used to use always `abspath`